# Angular Reactive Form Conditional Validation on Nested FormGroup FormControl?

Tags: angular

I am developing a User Form.

I am summarizing my issue, if the user ticked on medical policy checkbox then user have to fill the medical policy detail.

user form group code below:

```js
let userForm = this.myFormBuilder.group({
  userName: ['',Validators.required],
  password: ['',Validators.required],
  isMedicalPolicy: [false],
  medicalPolicyInfo: this.myFormBuilder.group({
    policyNumber: ['',Validator.maxLength(10)], // how to apply conditional required validation here, 
      if is isMedicalPolicy value is true.
  });
});
```

Please help on this.

Comment: You'll need to observe changes on the `isMedicalPolicy` field value and then alter the validation of the other fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can watch for changes to individual form control values, then alter the validation of other controls based on the value.

Example:

```
const isMedicalPolicyControl = this.userForm.get('isMedicalPolicy');
const policyNumberControl = this.userForm.get('medicalPolicyInfo.policyNumber');

this.subscription = isMedicalPolicyControl.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {

  if (value) {
    policyNumberControl.setValidators([
      Validators.required,
      Validator.maxLength(10)
    ]);
  }
  else {
    policyNumberControl.setValue('');
    policyNumberControl.setValidators(null);
  }

  policyNumberControl.updateValueAndValidity();

});
```

You'll want to unsubscribe from the valueChanges observable when your component is destroyed.

Comment: Thanks, Sorry, If forgot to add maxLength validator on policyNumber field. As per the code, if I set the validator  null then my maxlength validation will not work. then how do I a manage or I need to add maxLength validator every time if value is true.

Comment: No worries. I've updated the sample code. Since your validators only apply if the isMedicalPolicy control has a value of `true`, you can just assign/de-assign them when the value changes.

Comment: Calling `policyNumberControl.updateValueAndValidity()` inside the function `isMedicalPolicyControl.valueChanges.subscribe` is causing an `infinite loop`

Answer (score 0):

you can also simply use ternary operators like:

```
 medicalPolicyInfo: this.myFormBuilder.group({
    policyNumber: ['', isMedicalPolicy ? [ Validator.maxLength(10), Validators.required]:[]]
     
  });
```